# Fine Uploader 3.0 get php changed filename after upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have little problem to get file name after upload (PHP script for upload change name with md5 what i want) but fine uploader work with file name what was uploaded from pc. I need to get file name from response of Ajax.

Any Idea ?

P.S. I use

- jQuery - 1.8.3
- Fine Uploader - 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you save files first on server, then just change files' names and keep them in a database?

Comment: I solved it.. in php script i send filename in response text and with callback "onComplete" i used responseJSON.upload_name :) it was simple and effective